# Not getting numbers of divs in google.co.in

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I'm hitting www.google.co.in and opening console of my web browser to count the number of divs, I'm getting undefined. But when I try the same code in another site, it is printing the number of divs in that site.

```
var divs = $('div');
console.log(divs.length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because google does not use jQuery. But many browser (like firefox and chrome) implement a default `$` operator (working only in the dev console).

But this `$` is like the old Prototype framework operator. `$` returns the first matching element or null. `$$` returns an array of all matching element (or an empty array).

So you should try this: `console.log($$('div').length);`

You can also do this without any `$` or `$$` operator:

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('div'));
```